# How to sync users from OpenLDAP to Keycloak?

Tags: kubernetes, keycloak, kubernetes-helm, openldap, idp

Installed `keycloak` and `openldap` by helm on Kubernetes cluster.

```
helm install openldap stable/openldap
helm install keycloak codecentric/keycloak
```

It can connect to openldap service

[image]

Created DIT in OpenLDAP as

[image]

When click `Synchronize all users` on the Keycloak page

[image]

Got this error:

> Success! Sync of users finished successfully. 0 imported users, 0 updated users, 5 users failed sync! See server log for more details

It didn't sync any users. How to see the log file? Where is it by default? I have login the keycloak pod in k8s but didn't find under `/var/log/` path.

---

If I set `Users DN` = `ou=users,dc=example,dc=org`, it works. It can sync the only one user under `users` ou. Why can't sync all the user data one time?

Answer (score 0):

Provide correct value in User Object Classes like inetOrgPerson. You can add multiple values separated by comma.